# When will IndexedDB be 'done'?

Tags: indexeddb

In the previous spec for IndexedDB (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-IndexedDB-20111206) the mode value for IDBDatabase transaction was a short. In the current spec (24 May 2012) it is now a string. FF12 still uses a short. The mode value determines whether you want a read-only transaction or a read-write transaction.

Does anyone know where to find out the progress of IndexedDB (ie when will it be done and we can use window.indexedDB instead of window.mozIndexedDB/webkitIndexedDB/msIndexedDB)? Unfortunately the spec gives no indication if this is a proposed "final" version or just one of many to come (with more breaking changes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we made the change to go from numeric values for transaction mode, cursor direction, etc, it was with the intent that it would be the last "big change" to the spec.

As with any standards development, things could still change if we find really fatal flaws in the spec, like if it's somehow self contradictory, or if implementing every aspect of it requires taking some very bad performance penalties.

However given that we've implemented almost all the features in Firefox since Firefox 11 (only missing a couple of minor things like transaction.error) we are confident that we can fix the remaining bugs without problem.

We're even hoping to remove the 'moz' prefix in Firefox 16, though no promises since we're not there yet.

Edit: Oh, and the Sync part of the spec won't be holding up finishing the async part. We in the latest version of the spec we marked the sync part as "at risk" so that if we feel that it's holding us back, we can remove it for the spec and add it to the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Not any time soon.

Although I don't know when the spec will be fully baked, I can say with certainty that it's not yet close. Aside from API incompatibilities between at least two major browsers, FF and Chrome, the IE10 implementation has yet to be released to the public.

Moreover, one might argue that IndexedDB is not "done" until the synchronous API is implemented for use in Web Workers, and at this point no browser vendors have even agreed to start work on that.

Answer (score 0):

For the implementation progress on new features have a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb).

For IndexedDB it currently lists only prefixed support in Firefox and Chrome. Ans support for the upcoming IE10.

As with many features it will be a de factor standard (and thus only modified slightly) long before the w3c standard is listed as final.

Comment: I can use IndexedDB in FF, chrome, IE, but they are for the previous version of the spec. This version has a breaking change - if you try to open a "readwrite" transaction you actually get back a READ_ONLY transaction. My question is really - when will the breaking changes stop??

Comment: @dangibson I don't think anybody can say at the moment. If you want to use it now, maybe you are better off using some wrapper library, which takes care of a consistent interface over the changing API. Maybe that question is of interest to you: [JavaScript Library to Bridge IndexedDB and WebSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6116053/1169798).

Comment: There actually is someone that can say - the spec authors, I've just emailed one of them, Jonas Sicking from Mozilla. Hopefully I'll get a response.

Comment: if you do get a response will you forward a copy to indexeddb-users? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/indexeddb-users

Comment: He did reply (really quickly too) and also added an answer to this question (which I've accepted)