# How long will Web SQL Database remain in the browsers?

Tags: html, client-side, data-storage

I am currently using web SQL database in my chrome and safari browsers. 
This runs pretty well for my requirement.
The code is up and running and makes use HTML concepts.
I have done some R&D and seen that this technology is deprecated and no longer supported.
Most of them are suggesting to use Indexed DB. I dont think this is a feasible option for me as there is a lot of code involved.

I still see Web sql DB in the latest browsers and my app is running smoothly.

**My Question and worry here is, are they going to completely remove WEB SQL from Chrome and safari browsers?**

If that happens I will be totally Doomed.

Comment: My question is simple Mr. Raju. Are they goin to completely remove WEB sql from all the browsers and just keep Indexed DB?

Comment: it was already deprecated. follow the specification updates, you will get more info. and browsers drop websql support soon in their next releases.

Comment: Mr. Konga raju I respect your Views. I have already done some R&D on this and you can check this site which says that they wont drop WEB SQL. But still i wanted some expert review or links where they say it will be dropped in future versions of browsers.
http://caniuse.com/sql-storage
Also i feel people who are voting this question down are not doing any R&D and simple saying this question is not useful. 
I have still seen people recommending WEB SQL. Thats the reason this question was popped

Comment: yes all major browsers will drop websql support so better move to indexedDB.

Comment: So it's November 2016 and it still exists in browsers. Any update to this? Or does it still stick around because IndexedDB is still too buggy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are targeting for mobile browsers you can go with Web Sql , or else you can go with index db. check out the link 
[Offline access - SQLite or Indexed DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247380/offline-access-sqlite-or-indexeddb)

Comment: I am targeting for mobile browsers Mr. karthik.

Comment: For mobile browser you can go with web sql, as many mobile browsers still not support index db. If you have concerns with db size then you go with phone gap , as phonegap has plugin which will help you to access native sqlite , I find this iOS phonegap plugin  in the link https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin, for android you can go with phonegap sqlite plugin.

Comment: Keep in mind that Windows Phone does not support WebSQL.