# Offline Mobile Web Application Storage

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, local-storage, offline

I am looking at writing a mobile web application with offline support, and would prefer to use the HTML5 offline capabilities instead of something like phonegap.

A requirement of the app will be that it store 2 collections of different types of objects (lets call them Books and Authors) which, when online, it will download from the server.  If it didn't need to be offline then I'd be using some flavour of SQL tables or (preferably) a document-based DB to store these items, but having done some basic investigation I haven't found anything that feels "right" that works offline.

My question is: what is the *best* strategy to store those items?  What I have considered so far:

**HTML5 localStorage** - Seems to have relatively wide support but is limited to key value pairs, which would mean a slightly unpleasant data structure - maybe having a `total-authors` key and then a series of `author-1....author-n` key-document pairs.  This feels wrong to me - like I am trying to work around the intent of the storage.

**CouchDb** - I've worked with CouchDb quite a bit in the past so would love to use it or an equivalent, but "proper" CouchDb would require a native app (with which I have no experience), and  the 2 in-browser equivalents I have seen don't quite seem to do the trick: **Lawnchair** doesn't seem to add much to the `localStorage` option and **BrowserCouch** doesn't appear to have had much activity recently (which always makes me wary).

**WebDb** - Looks like it would be perfect...except it seems to be officially discontinued and doesn't look to be widely supported

**Gears** - Discontinued

**IndexedDB** - Limited browser support for now (at least according to caniuse)

I'm convinced there must be *something* out there that does what I want, and I've just managed to somehow overlook it.  Can anyone suggest the way this ought to be done (as opposed to a way it *could* be done)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no browser-native simple solution as far I know; you'll have to either go with localStorage or develop for both WebDB and IndexedDB.

But non-native you could use a abstraction layer like [lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) (uses localStorage by default, plugins available for indexeddb, webdb, ...) or the one [SO-user Gatapia wrote for picnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154795/indexdb-websql-in-4-months/3157055) (uses indexeddb & webdb & gears) that you [can find on github](https://github.com/PicNet/picnet_closure_repo/tree/master/src/pn/data).

Comment: So far Lawnchair is my favourite option, and I hadn't seen the second suggestion so will look into that - thanks.  I'll leave the question open for now in the hope that someone knows of a silver bullet though :)